# S3's SSE-C headers being ignored?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am attempting to use S3's server-side encryption for customer keys. I created a bucket which allows anonymous users to upload objects, and then attempted to upload an object like so:

```
$ http -v PUT 'https://BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com/test.txt' \
  "x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-algorithm:AES256" \
  "x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-key:BASE64DKEY" \
  "x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-key-MD5:EmqLRYqvItSQUzWCBAdF+A=="  \
  < ~/test.txt

PUT /test.txt HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.8.0
x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-algorithm: AES256
x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-key: BASE64KEY
x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-key-MD5: EmqLRYqvItSQUzWCBAdF+A==

This is a test file

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 22:12:26 GMT
ETag: "5dd39cab1c53c2c77cd352983f9641e1"
Server: AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2: AUOQUfmHEwOPqqvDd5X7aTYk+SX043gVFvM3wlgbzfRcpQsXIxXOFjrTRAM+B2T9Ns6Z/C26lBg=
x-amz-request-id: 6063C14465E4B090
```

Everything seemed to be working, although the encryption headers didn't come back in the response. So, I attempted to fetch my new object:

```
$ curl 'https://BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com/test.txt'
This is a test file
```

Oh no! My encryption headers appear to have been completely ignored, and the object has been stored in plaintext. As far as I can tell from [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html), I am uploading the object correctly. Any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong?

What's really awful is that if I do a GET and include this key, I get back a 200. That's terrifying. I could easily have started using these calls and never noticed that no encryption was being performed.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered what I believe to be the cause. When I upload objects to S3 anonymously (but providing a key), the server-side encryption credentials are completely ignored, and my object is stored in plaintext. The credentials are also ignored when downloading, so the download works fine.

However, if I authenticate as any AWS user, the headers are respected, and my object is stored with appropriate encryption.

So, important note to SSE-C users: make sure you don't upload any objects anonymously, or the whole feature silently ignores your encryption keys entirely!

Comment: Sounds like it would be better if they rejected the upload in this scenario.

Comment: I agree. Infinitely better.